Error in login Session store not set on request?
I have Laravel as the backend and Nuxt js as frontend i used Session Sanctum here is the set up:
in my cors.php :
 'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'], 

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

in app.php
->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->statefulApi();
    })

in sanctum.php:
'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
        Sanctum::currentApplicationUrlWithPort()
    ))),

.env file:
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS="is.test:9090"

my nuxt.config.ts:
  devServer: {
    port: 9090,
    host: "is.test",
  },

with this setup, everything works fine when the backend and frontend are local on my device... when I deploy the backend on a server and try to connect the from local Nuxt to the backend (deployed) I get error in Login Session store not set on request.
here is my .env in production:
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS="is.test:9090"

